# netCDF to *.csv without Loops(!)

Tags: python, arrays, csv, matrix, netcdf

I'm having some performance and 'ugly code' problem and maybe some of you can help.
I have to export data from **netCDF-files** to ***.csv**. For this I wrote some python code. Let's take a 3-dim netcdf-File:

```py
def to3dim_csv():
  var = ncf.variables['H2O'] #e.g. data for 'H2O' values
  one,two,three = var.shape #variable dimension shape e.g. (551,42,94)
  dim1,dim2,dim3 = var.dimensions #dimensions e.g. (time,lat,lon)

  if crit is not None:
    bool1 = foo(dim1,crit,ncf) #boolean table: ("value important?",TRUE,FALSE)
    bool2 = foo(dim2,crit,ncf)
    bool3 = foo(dim3,crit,ncf)

  writer.writerow([dim1,dim2,dim3,varn])
  for i in range(one):
    for k in range(two):
      for l in range(three):
        if bool1[i] and bool2[k] and bool3[l]:
          writer.writerow([
                        ncf.variables[dim1][i],
                        ncf.variables[dim2][k],
                        ncf.variables[dim3][l],
                        var[i,k,l],
                        ])
  ofile.close()

  # Sample csv output is like:
  # time,lat,lon,H2O
  # 1,90,10,100
  # 1,90,11,90
  # 1,91,10,101
```

I want to remove the `for val in range(d):` blocks. Perhaps using a **recursiv function**, like:

```py
var = ncf.variables['H2O']
dims = [d for d in var.dimensions]
shapes = [var.variables[d].shape for d in dims]
bools = [bool_table(d,crit,ncf) for d in dims]
dims.append('H2O')
writer.writerow(dims)
magic_function(data)

def magic_function(data):

   [enter code]

   writer.writerow(data)
   magic_function(left_data)
```

**Update:**
For anyone who is interested. This works instantaneous ...

```
def data_to_table(dataset, var):
    assert isinstance(dataset,xr.Dataset), 'Dataset must be xarray.Dataset'
    obj = getattr(dataset, var)
    table = np.zeros((obj.data.size, obj.data.ndim+1), dtype=np.object_)
    table[:,0] = obj.data.flat
    for i,d in enumerate(obj.dims):
        repeat = np.prod(obj.data.shape[i+1:])
        tile = np.prod(obj.data.shape[:i])
        dim = getattr(dataset, d)
        dimdata = dim.data
        dimdata = np.repeat(dimdata, repeat)
        dimdata = np.tile(dimdata, tile)
        table[:,i+1] = dimdata.flat
    return table

def export_to_csv(dataset, var, filename, size=None):
    obj = getattr(dataset, var)
    header = [var] + [x for x in obj.dims]
    tabular = data_to_table(dataset, var)
    size = slice(None,size,None) if size else slice(None,None,None)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,dialect=csv.excel)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(tabular[size])
```

Comment: 1. it looks ugly if I have to repeat the code for every n-dim.
2. it takes a lot of time to go through all the data. Maybe someone has an idea of using `ncdump` or similar function to increase the speed -- [the comment got removed I answered to]

Comment: using a recursive function here will not bring performance gains

Comment: numpy boolean indexing of the arrays should speed this up?

Comment: @M4rtini: What do you mean? I use the boolean tables for deciding if I want the value associated with the row or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Get the indexes of bol1\2\3 and combine them while fetching the relevant values.

```
    with open('numpy.csv', 'wb') as f:
        out_csv = csv.writer(f)
        header = ['dim1','dim2','dim3','varn']
        out_csv.writerow(header)
        bol1_indices = np.nonzero(bol1)[0]
        bol2_indices = np.nonzero(bol2)[0]
        bol3_indices = np.nonzero(bol3)[0]
        out_csv.writerows(([a[i, k, l], dim1[i], dim2[k], dim3[l]] for i in bol1_indices for k in bol2_indices for  l in bol3_indices))
```

Comment: Thank you M4rtini. This one works. And it is about 5-10% faster then the loops. Do you have any other hints?

Comment: Actually, in this case i think most of the runtime is from the write to file part. Not sure how to speed that up. Except of maybe buying a faster hdd.

Comment: Thx. Hope you don't mind that I'm not marking this as a solution. I want to wait a little longer. Maybe some of the netCDF experts can hint to special methods for this...

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in python will always be slow because the raw data is not in the same format that you want to save. Python will have to create the indices and save one value per line. What do you need the csv for? I recommend using [ncdump](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/ncdump.html), which converts very quickly to a simple text file. If you must use csv, then you can use the nc2text utility from [FAN language utilities](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/fan_utils.html) (see e.g. [this page](http://www.narccap.ucar.edu/data/ascii-howto.html)).

Comment: I need the csv-format for saving the data into SciDB. I'll look into FAN and give you some feedback. Any experience with SciDB?

Comment: @UCU, No, I have not used SciDB.